# Filter changes the focus of TextInput after few words and does not allow to enter long words

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

While using `Filter` in a `List` react admin does not allow you to type a long text and changes the focus from the `TextInput` after typing some characters.
Below sample code from react-native docs can be used to reproduce this issue.

```
import { Filter, ReferenceInput, SelectInput, TextInput, List } from 'react-admin';
const PostFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <TextInput label="Search" source="q" resettable alwaysOn />
    </Filter>
);

export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List filters={<PostFilter />} {...props}>
        // ...
    </List>
);
```

How can I tell react-admin not to remove the focus from the `TextInput` and let user allow to enter `Text` continuously.